# What is the cause of this segmentation fault error in PHP

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

So my local PHP setup was running fine before yesterday afternoon, I have different versions of PHP installed in my system, and while trying to install imagemagick /imagick, I came across an issue, after the package had been installed via Pecl

N.B: I'm running shivammathur/php/php@7.3, Other codebases are able to work fine without any issue, but this one particular one keeps on throwing segmentation faults.

I have also tried other PHP versions, yet the problematic codebase keeps throwing that

I have also removed all imagemagick/imagick package

I have cleared all my PHP setup, and then started again, but still same issue,

Is anyone able to help with the meaning of lldp debugging report?

I have tried different solutions listed on StackOverflow, but none helped

This is the part of the error

```
[Fri Aug 25 22:34:42.452825 2023] [core:notice] [pid 18471] AH00052: child pid 19324 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Aug 25 22:34:42.453303 2023] [core:notice] [pid 18471] AH00052: child pid 18479 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Aug 25 22:34:43.454383 2023] [core:notice] [pid 18471] AH00052: child pid 18476 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Aug 25 22:34:48.460663 2023] [core:notice] [pid 18471] AH00052: child pid 19371 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

My LLDP Debugging report

```
Process 18471 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00000001a1b8f030 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`:
->  0x1a1b8f030 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1a1b8f050               ; <+40>
    0x1a1b8f034 <+12>: pacibsp
    0x1a1b8f038 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1a1b8f03c <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (httpd) stopped.
Executable module set to "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.57_1/bin/httpd".
Architecture set to: arm64-apple-macosx-.
(lldb) bt all
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00000001a1b8f030 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 8
    frame #1: 0x000000010494c528 libapr-1.0.dylib`apr_sleep + 84
    frame #2: 0x0000000104716bdc httpd`ap_wait_or_timeout + 140
    frame #3: 0x000000010491d548 mod_mpm_prefork.so`prefork_run + 1184
    frame #4: 0x0000000104715fbc httpd`ap_run_mpm + 84
    frame #5: 0x0000000104709500 httpd`main + 2200
    frame #6: 0x00000001a186bf28 dyld`start + 2236
  thread #2
    frame #0: 0x00000001a1b85c08 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue, and the only workaround I've found so far is to run httpd in debug mode using -X key. This is not a solution, but rather a way to identify the real cause, as it's probably somewhere between httpd and macos.

Comment: Ooh, I later had to use Nginx, as it was an Apache issue, so may be you might consider using it